# Add custom language to Spacy 3.0 and train pipelines in it

Tags: python, spacy, spacy-3

I've been using Spacy 2.3.1 until now. I had created my own custom class inherited from `Language` class and trained a NER pipeline using Python script in it.

But in Spacy 3.0 a bunch of handy CLI commands and configs are introduced in order to train custom pipelines which are highly recommended to use instead of Python scripts. Here is an example of config  for `nlp` object:

```
...

[nlp]
lang = "fa"
pipeline = ["transformer","ner"]
batch_size = 32
disabled = []
before_creation = null
after_creation = null
after_pipeline_creation = null
tokenizer = {"@tokenizers":"spacy.Tokenizer.v1"}

...
```

As you can see the `lang` attribute should be one of the predefined languages in the Spacy library.
Is there any way that I can indicate in the config that I need to create an object of my own custom language as `nlp` object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's actually [a section on this](https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features#language-subclass) in the docs. The basic idea is you have to add your language to the registry. Example from the docs:

```
import spacy
from spacy.lang.en import English

class CustomEnglishDefaults(English.Defaults):
    stop_words = set(["custom", "stop"])

@spacy.registry.languages("custom_en")
class CustomEnglish(English):
    lang = "custom_en"
    Defaults = CustomEnglishDefaults

# This now works! 
nlp = spacy.blank("custom_en")
```